# Is  “He picked up a quarrel” correct?

Tags: grammaticality, collocation

Is this sentence  grammatically correct?

> He picked up a quarrel.

Comment: Sounds like "India-speak" ...

Comment: Without some context and a meaningful sentence, it is quite impossible to say if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 15):

> He picked up a quarrel.

Is it syntactically correct? Yes, of course.

Is it semantically correct? Less clear.  Was he a crossbowman who’s spilt his quarrels on the ground?  Or was he a short-wave operator trying to tune in a distant channel of people bickering?

In either of those cases, sure.  But if we’re talking about somebody being quarrelsome and starting one up, then no. One starts quarrels; one does not pick them up.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean that he's about to shoot a stubby arrow from a crossbow, then yes. If you mean that he tried to start a fight, the idiom is, "He picked a fight".

Comment: Unless the two quarrelers had to take a break for some reason. In that case, when the argument resumed, the quarrel could be _picked up_ where it was left off.

Comment: @J.R. Agreed, but that would be pretty specialized. (Admittedly, so would the crossbow use.)